# Python unittest module invoking wrong class?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am working on a Django project and some unittests seemed to be failing seemingly unexpectedly.  I was able to track down the failures to how it seems the VSCode/unittest testing framework is calling the test cases.  I was able to reproduce the behavior with the simple setup below.

```py
import unittest

class USER_STORY_1_8_1(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print('USER_STORY_1_8_1:setUp')

    def tearDown(self):
        print('USER_STORY_1_8_1:tearDown')

    def test_run(self):
        print('USER_STORY_1_8_1:test_run')

class USER_STORY_1_8_10(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print('USER_STORY_1_8_10:setUp')

    def tearDown(self):
        print('USER_STORY_1_8_10:tearDown')

    def test_run(self):
        print('USER_STORY_1_8_10:test_run')

class USER_STORY_1_8_11(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print('USER_STORY_1_8_11:setUp')

    def tearDown(self):
        print('USER_STORY_1_8_11:tearDown')

    def test_run(self):
        print('USER_STORY_1_8_11:test_run')
```

[Screen Capture of VSCode project Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPvWO.png)

It seems that for similarly named test cases like these:

```py
class USER_STORY_1_8_1(unittest.TestCase)
class USER_STORY_1_8_10(unittest.TestCase)
class USER_STORY_1_8_11(unittest.TestCase)
```

instead of calling each one in an exact-match type of way, it's doing some kind of 'USER_STORY_1_8_1.*' ordered resolution so that a call to USER_STORY_1_8_1 actually calls into the setUp() for USER_STORY_1_8_11.  If USER_STORY_1_8_11 is unavailable (e.g. commented out), then i resolves to USER_STORY_1_8_10. And if neither is available, only then it calls the correct USER_STORY_1_8_1.

Is there anyway to override this behavior?

Comment: I think you should probably report the issue directly in the plugin's Github project https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues. I have tested your code with VSC 1.43.2 and the Python plutin 2020.3.71659 and I have experienced the same issue. The only difference is that the test is reported as still running even though the other with similar name completed successfully. **Also consider** using a different test framework. I've checked the same code but running it with the **_pytest_ framework and all tests run without any issues**. That makes me think that it might be a _unittest_ behavi

Comment: @lexotero I also originally thought it was a unittest behavior.  However if I go command line and run `python test.py USER_STORY_1_8_1` it runs as expected running the USER_STORY_1_8_1 TestCase.  I've opened an Issue Report here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/10972 and hopefully we can get some clarification